# How to parse a particular javascript variable in an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, screen-scraping

I have a Ruby/Rails app and am trying to screen-scrape a page to get at some data. Here's what the html looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
<h1>Blah</h1>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
 var foo = "abc";               
 var bar = {interesting_json_here};
 var baz = "xyz";
</script>
Other uninteresting content and tags here
</body>
</html>
```

I don't care about ***anything*** except the contents of bar.

How do I get at bar and then iterate through it to parse the contents of the json in bar?

Comment: It "depends" - can you give a sample of that json - as close to reality would be best.  If bar is contained on one line, and only occurs in the page once, then you could be lazy and use a regex to extract it.  Because the alternative - extracting the javascript block using the DOM and then parsing Javascript is a lot harder.

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = "abc";               
var bar = {interesting_json_here};
var baz = "xyz";
for(var i in bar) {
    alert(bar[i]['json_key']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you tell me whats the json object like? If the structure is always the same then you can just directly access everything, you dont need to iterate through it using a loop.
var test = jsonObject.something.something etc.

Comment: Assuming that it is always the same

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the HTML looks like...

```
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
<h1>Blah</h1>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
 var foo = "abc";               
 var bar = { "alpha": "beta" };
 var bar2 = { 'alpha': 'gamma' };
 var baz = "xyz";
</script>
Other uninteresting content and tags here
</body>
</html>
```

You could do some Ruby like

```
json_text = the_html.split("\n").each { |l|
  break $1 if (l.strip =~ /^var bar = (.*);$/)
}

require 'rubygems'
gem 'json'
require 'json'
json_data = JSON.parse(json_text)
puts json_data.inspect
```

Note: this is a very brittle approach - changes in HTML structure or JS layout will break things.

The biggest assumption is that the JSON will be on one line.

Answer (score 0):

```
json = JSON.parse($1) if html =~ /var bar = (.*);/
```